# Scala: Why can I pass a quite strange argument to the function?

Tags: scala

I have defined method `double`.

```
def double(i: Int): Int = i * 2

val p = double {
  print("Hello!");
  5
}

print(p)
```

As you can see we can pass not just integer argument, but we also can invoke some logic (`print`). Why can I do that? And how Scala do resolve it? What does really mean `{}` in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
val p = double({ //`{}` still means a block of code
  print("Hello!") 
  5
})
```

or even:

```
def block = { //might be `def block() { ... }`
  print("Hello!")
  5
}

val p = double(block) //calling the block here, it's equivalent to double(block())
```

So it's just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to help developers to build some handy [DSLs](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/05/designing-internal-dsls-in-scala.html), which are looking like native language parts.

Answer (score 3):

In this case {} means anonymous block of code. The result of invocation of code block equals to the last block's expression result.

Your code equivalent to this one

```
val p = double( {
  print("Hello!");
  5
})
```

Code block evaluation result is a parameter for double.
This works because block evaluation result is 5 and have Int type.

Function params evaluation doing before body of function will invoke.
First expression of code block is print and therefor print("Hello!"); will be called first. The last expression is 5 and take as function parameter.

```
val p = double(5)
```

And then print result of double is 10.

Total result of this code is printing to console

```
Hello!10
```

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned, the last expression of an anonymous block is returned; (obviously) nested anonymous blocks works as well,

```
val p = double {
  val a = 2
  val b = { println("Hello!"); 3 }
  a+b
}
Hello!
p: Int = 10
```

Note `p` type conveys the return type declared for `double`.

Likewise,

```
val p = double { 2 + { println("Hello!"); 3 } }
Hello!
p: Int = 10
```